# Receiving correct data but still getting bad request

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm getting a bad request 400 but I'm getting my data from backend perfectly. Also only happens if I use React Strict Mode. Not sure what's happening. Added the code I believe someone needs to find the problem

Backend:

Controller:
console.logging newLeaderboard gives me what I expect.

```js
export const updateQuestionLeaderboard = async (req, res) => {
  const { leaderboardId } = req.params;
  const { questionIndex, playerId, playerPoints } = req.body;
  let leaderboard;

  try {
    leaderboard = await Leaderboard.findById(leaderboardId);
    leaderboard.questionLeaderboard[questionIndex].questionResultList.push({
      playerId,
      playerPoints,
    });

    const newLeaderboard = await leaderboard.save();
    console.log({ newLeaderboard });
    // console.log(newLeaderboard.questionLeaderboard[0].questionResultList);
    res.status(201).json(newLeaderboard);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```

Here is my route code.
Route:

```js
router.patch(
  "/:leaderboardId/questionleaderboard",
  verifyToken,
  updateQuestionLeaderboard
);
```

FrontEnd:
Action:

```js
export const updateQuestionLeaderboard =
  (questionResult, id, token) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:3000/leaderboard/${id}/questionleaderboard`,
        {
          method: "PATCH",
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(questionResult),
        }
      );
      console.log({ questionResult });
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log({ data });
      dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_QUESTION_LEADERBOARD", payload: data });
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

My HostPage on frontend:

```js
  const updateLeaderboard = (data, id, score) => {
    console.log("GIVE LEADERBOARD ID", id);
    dispatch(updateQuestionLeaderboard(data, id, token))
      .then((question) => {
        console.log({ question });
        setQuestionResult(question.questionLeaderboard[data.questionIndex]);
        let leaderboardData = {
          questionIndex: data.questionIndex,
          playerId: data.playerId,
          playerCurrentScore: score,
        };
        return dispatch(updateCurrentLeaderboard(leaderboardData, id, token));
      })
      .then((leaderboard) => {
        console.log({ leaderboard });
        console.log("DATA QUESTION INDEX", data.questionIndex);
        setCurrentLeaderboard(
          leaderboard.currentLeaderboard[data.questionIndex]
        );
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle any errors that might occur during the async operations
        console.error(error);
      });
  };
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution

```
export const updateQuestionLeaderboard =
  (questionResult, id, token) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const data = await Promise.resolve().then(() =>
        fetch(`http://localhost:3000/leaderboard/${id}/questionleaderboard`, {
          method: "PATCH",
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(questionResult),
        }).then((response) => response.json())
      );
      console.log({ data });
      dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_QUESTION_LEADERBOARD", payload: data });
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Still happening the same. Thanks for the response.